# What happens after a Git clone is "done."?

Tags: git

I have a large repository which I ran `git gc --aggressive` on that
I'm trying to clone on a local file system. I would expect it to
complete very quickly with hard links but it's taking about 6min to
complete with no checkout (`git clone -n`). I see the message `Cloning
into 'repos'... done.` appear after a few seconds but then Git just
hangs there for another 6min, despite the claim that it's "done". Any idea what it's doing at this point and how I can speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are cloning it exactly, but providing source without the protocol can improve the speed greatly:

`git clone -m /path/to/source /path/to/target`

Will be much faster than

`git clone -m file:///path/to/source /path/to/target`

Some other clues, that might prove helpful:

- What git version are you using, try to use latest.
- What is the filesystem you are doing this on, does it support hardlinks?
- Are the directories you are copying between on the same disk/partition?

Comment: I am cloning on a local NFS-mounted file system. I am using the latest version of Git (1.8.0-rc2). The file system supports hard links and it is even slower without them. NFS hides the disk from me but the files can be copied with hard links. The problem seems to be in update_remote_refs(), with some taking several links to complete. I started a thread on the Git mailing list but seem to have lost their interest in fixing the bug.